# How does DEFLATE optimize this so much?

Tags: compression, gzip, zlib, deflate, lz77

I am trying to understand the deflate algorithm, and I have read up on Huffman codes as well as LZ77 compression. I was toying around with compression sizes of different strings, and I stumbled across something I could not explain. The string `aaa` when compressed, both through [zlib](https://zlib.net/) and [gzip](https://www.gzip.org/), turns out to be the same size as `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` (36 `a`s).

Before reading about this I would have assumed the compressor does something like storing 36*a instead of each character individually, but I could not find anywhere in the specifications where that is mentioned.

Using fixed Huffman code yielded the same result, so I assume the space-saving lies in LZ77, but that only uses distance-length pairs. How would that allow a 3 length string to expand by 12 times without increasing in size?

Interrupting the string of `a`s with one or several `b`s in the middle drastically increases the size. If distance-length pairs is what's doing the job, why could it not just skip over the `b`s when searching backwards? Or is Huffman codes being utilized and I misunderstood what fixed Huffman codes implies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 36 "a"s are effectively run-length encoded by LZ77 by giving the first "a" as a literal, and then a match with a distance of one, and a length of 35. The length can be as much as 258 for deflate.

Look online for tutorials on LZ77, Huffman coding, and deflate. You can disassemble the resulting compressed data with [infgen](https://github.com/madler/infgen) to get more insight into how the data is being represented.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so its basically just looping the search-buffer. Thanks!